# Google Play silent log-in

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-games

So I'm working on an android game and I am using Google Play, GoogleApiClient to be specific. Now when my game logs in, it pauses the game and logs in. The problem I have is that it pauses the game, and does a loading thing on top of my game. I've played other games that use the Google Play Services that have a log in, and they don't freeze up or display a loading notification over the game. Their games just run like normal, and then the little Google signed in alert drops down. I am wondering what I am doing wrong, or if there is an obvious trick to make it not dawdle behind. If anyone needs any code, let me know what part you need the code of, and I will post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [setShowConnectingPopup()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.GamesOptions.Builder#setShowConnectingPopup(boolean)).

Also review this [guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) for details on setShowConnectingPopup() usage and asynchronous login.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helped. It still shows the circle display when it is loading but it no longer shows the google play box anymore which is what I was trying to achieve. Is there a way to hide the circle loading or no? I looked at Async() and even tried client.connect inside of that, but it still showed the circle load. 
Either way, setShowConnectionPopup() was definitely a big help.

Comment: You could try [setViewForPopups()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#setViewForPopups(android.view.View)) and set the view to something that's not actually visible. It would hide any important popups, though.

Answer (score 0):

If your game activity calls `connect()` in the `onStart()` method, so then `GoogleApiClient` will attempt to sign in silently.

Comment: Everyone has said that, but that didn't work for me. 
What I did find to work was to just not ever automatically sign the user out in the onStop() event. Doing that allows them all the access to the scores and achievements without having the spinning circle pop up.